# Mail sent with PHP mail are not shown in my mails Sent folder

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, imap, codeigniter-3

I'm sending email from my webmail accounts to any email address.

Mails are sending successfully, but how can I have this mails in **my webmail account sent folder**.

I use codeigniter email sent functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include your code in your question.

This isn't PHPMailer's job, but it's related. Take a look at [the end of the gmail example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps#L74). It includes a section that uploads a sent message to your IMAP folder. The basic idea is that after you've received a successful `send()` response, get a copy of the message and upload it to your IMAP mailbox:

```
...
//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
    //Section 2: IMAP
    if (save_mail($mail)) {
        echo "Message saved!";
    }
}
//Section 2: IMAP
//IMAP commands requires the PHP IMAP Extension, found at: https://php.net/manual/en/imap.setup.php
//Function to call which uses the PHP imap_*() functions to save messages: https://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php
//You can use imap_getmailboxes($imapStream, '/imap/ssl') to get a list of available folders or labels, this can
//be useful if you are trying to get this working on a non-Gmail IMAP server.
function save_mail($mail)
{
    //You can change 'Sent Mail' to any other folder or tag
    $path = "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}[Gmail]/Sent Mail";
    //Tell your server to open an IMAP connection using the same username and password as you used for SMTP
    $imapStream = imap_open($path, $mail->Username, $mail->Password);
    $result = imap_append($imapStream, $path, $mail->getSentMIMEMessage());
    imap_close($imapStream);
    return $result;
}
```

CodeIgniter uses a wrapper around PHPMailer, but you should be able to get access to the necessary data somehow, and the IMAP code is not specific to PHPMailer.

Comment: Thank you for your response, imap_append worked for me excelentlly

Comment: Just a note for others: Gmail, specifically, if sent through smtp.gmail.com, will automatically place a copy in the Sent folder.  This is non-standard behaviour though.

Comment: @user5677872 - if you liked my answer and it solved your problem, please mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: anyone know how to find the path "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}[Gmail]/Sent Mail" for different email accounts? (I am using blacknight on my dedicated server)