# How to save sent email in sen box using phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am sending emails to my subscribers using phpmailer. Emails are sending tot my clients successfully but I am not getting email in my sent box. Is there a way to save sending emails in sent box ??? Any help would be highly  appreciable. Here is my code:

```
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$link= mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass", "db") or die ("could not connect to mysql"); 
//if($link){echo "connect";}
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';


$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
     $query = "select customer_email from subscribers";
     $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("No customer in the table");;

     while($values = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

         $toemail = $values['customer_email'];


    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = '(myhost)';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = '(my email)';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '(my password)';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('haris.khan@premier.com.pk', 'Premier');
    $mail->addAddress(''.$toemail.'', ''.$name.'');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addReplyTo('haris.khan@premier.com.pk', 'Information');

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject for IT';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
   echo 'Message has been sent';
}
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: You are only sending mails out, there is no code given to save the sent mail somewhere ;)

Comment: Or have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47472170/mail-sent-with-php-mail-are-not-shown-in-my-mails-sent-folder

Comment: I am using namecheap hosting

Answer (score -1):

Saving a sent copy of the email is a function of a mail program like outlook, gmail etc.

If you would like to archive a copy of the sent mail, you can bcc the email to another (or the same) email address. Then setup a filter rule on the mailbox to move it to the sent directory.

Comment: this is not true...as above, you can automate create a SENT email into the Sent folder.